# How can I handle an access token coming from an external API (without auth in the middleware) in a Laravel App?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, token

I have an external API which sends notifications to my Laravel APP.
I am parsing the notification `json` and then I'm trying to get detailed information about that notification (a different endpoint, of course).

The problem:

- The API sends the notification via a `POST` to an url in my app. (in frontend middleware, without auth).
- Based on the notification data, I access another endpoint, so I can get details
- Every time I access another endpoint, I will need another access token.

How can I save this token and use it until he expires? I do not want to regenerate the token every time I have a notification. Every `POST` notification has another session, so I cannot save it in the session.

Comment: Have you considered caching it or storing to database?

Comment: Have you tried to include it in the request parameter when calling the other endpoint? e.g `redirect()->route('nexturl', ['token' => $the_token_i_received])` I hope you got my point.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the `redirect` and the `route`. I think Caching is a solution.